# Combine multiple rows in to one with the same ID

Tags: sql-server

I currently have the table structure below where I have a custom ID called SubNo which ties all of the records from that insert together but ideally in an SQL query i need all of the values to output as one row for each SubNo

| SubNo | Type | FID | FVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2173 | SOS | YourName | J Bloggs |
| 2173 | SOS | YourDate | 2023-10-30 |
| 2173 | SOS | YourTime | 07:30 |
| 2174 | SOS | YourName | N.E Body |
| 2174 | SOS | YourDate | 2023-10-31 |
| 2174 | SOS | YourTime | 09:00 |

This is what I am trying to achieve is this output

| SubNo | Type | YourName | YourDate | YourTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2173 | SOS | J Bloggs | 2023-10-30 | 07:30 |
| 2174 | SOS | N.E Body | 2023-10-31 | 09:00 |

I currently run the SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Core] 
WHERE Type = 'SOS' 
  AND FID IN ('YourName','YourDate','YourTime')
ORDER BY SubNo DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

which returns the first table

I have tried to use `JOIN` and `STRING_AGG` without success.

Comment: Use a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) query to convert row values into columns.

Comment: This isn't combining multiple rows, this convers the EAV antipattern to proper rows. If you know the columns in advance you can use `PIVOT` or `MAX(IIF(FID='YourName',FVal,NULL))` to convert the row attributes into columns. Both options require roughly the same amount of code. If you don't know the attributes you'll have to use dynamic SQL that generates the PIVOT or `IIF` clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the columns in advance you can use the conditional aggregation using `MAX()` :

```
select SubNo, Type, max(case when FID = 'YourName' then FVal end) as YourName,
                    max(case when FID = 'YourDate' then FVal end) as YourDate,
                    max(case when FID = 'YourTime' then FVal end) as YourTime
from mytable
where Type = 'SOS'
group by  SubNo, Type
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/i4E4oY4_)